# How does Windows 10 run on a Mac that officially only supports Windows 7?

Tags: macbook-pro, bootcamp, windows

Does anyone have experience with Windows 10 having specific driver-related issues on a similar Mac that only supports (has Bootcamp drivers for) Windows 7? I have this MacBook Pro: [Apple MacBook Pro "Core 2 Duo" 2.4 17" (SR) Specs](http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook_pro/specs/macbook-pro-core-2-duo-2.4-17-santa-rosa-specs.html)

Apple supports up to Windows 7 on this Mac with Bootcamp drivers. I upgraded it to Windows 8 (not supported by Apple) and it still works just fine (Windows 8.1 now), except for some quirks like the volume/brightness bezel not showing up when I use those controls.

I am a little concerned that installing Windows 10 might break something that can't be fixed, and I'll have to wipe everything and figure out how to go back to Windows 8, which would be a pain. Does anyone know if Windows 10 is successfully able to use the Windows 7 bootcamp drivers? …or should I be the one to test it out and see if it works okay? :D

Comment: The GA release of Windows 10 hasn't happened yet nor is it yet officially supported on Apple-branded hardware via Boot Camp.  Unless Apple includes the appropriate and necessary drivers for your hardware, yet to be determined and most likely will not, you'll most likely have some issues.

Comment: I know it's not released yet; it's scheduled for release tomorrow, so I'm posting the question now. I am 100% certain that Apple will not release Windows 10 Bootcamp drivers for my Mac; as I said, my Mac only supports up to Windows 7. I am capable of concluding I may have some issues; that is why I asked the question—I want to know specifically what issues I can expect when Windows 10 is installed. ;)

Comment: smoooosher, see my reply to user3439894. Additionally, I'm not asking how a given user "feels," but for specific problems, such as the one I gave in my question: I don't see the bezel when changing volume or brightness (but I can still change the volume or brightness). I'm asking for specifics, like do the volume and brightness keys stop working? Does the keyboard or trackpad stop working? Things like that. It's a relatively simple, matter-of-fact question: Basically, do the drivers keep working, or not?

Comment: My Mac is a mid 2007 20 inch iMac and I started with Windows 7 64 bit. I did a clean install of Windows 8 64 bit, followed by an upgrade to 8.1 via the  Microsoft Store. Through all of this I used the same Boot Camp Support software even though officially my computer only supports Windows 7/Vista/XP 32 bit. I intend to do an clean install Windows 10 64 bit and do not anticipate any problems. I guess you intend to upgrade to Windows 10. Have you given any thought to backing up your current Windows 8.1 install?

Comment: I've withdrawn my comments as the updates to the post clarify the type of information sought.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft tried to focus on backwards compatibility with Windows 10, supposedly retaining support for drivers designed for Vista. I've been running Windows 10 on a newer Mac and it works fine. I'm sure you'll have no issues.

Answer (score 1):

I am running Windows 10 Enterprise on Bootcamp as well as in Parallels. In both cases it works amazingly stable and until now without any problems :)