# Bluetooth keyboard not working after update to Windows 10

Tags: keyboard, bootcamp, windows, driver, dual-boot

I updated my (native) bootcamp instance to Windows 10 from Windows 8.1, but now the apple bluetooth keyboard doesn't seem to work anymore. The bluetooth screen says 'driver error' on the device.

I've tried:

- Ran Apple Software Update and updated boot camp
- Uninstalling the device
- Unpairing + pairing again

Can someone provide guidance to get this to work?

Comment: @Tetsujin Win 10 should be officially supported by boot camp 6: http://www.informationweek.com/software/operating-systems/apples-boot-camp-6-supports-windows-10/a/d-id/1321766

Comment: Didn't realise it was out yet

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The new Keyboard driver on Bootcamp broke the connection for my keyboard under Windows 10 and it might break yours too.

So after using the solution from Zidad for the last couple of months (thank you) I decided to find a better solution to be able to use the Fn button and all the volume and multimedia functions of the Apple keyboard, here is what you need to do:

1. You need the Apple Keyboard driver that comes in the Bootcamp 5, you can either download the full pack from Apple (version 5.1.5621 works), or download only the keyboard driver from my dropbox (64bit windows only):

https://www.dropbox.com/s/jexvjcg2zlmjg3e/AppleKeyboardInstaller64.exe?dl=1

```
   •If you downloaded the file above proceed to step 4.
```

2. Unzip the BootCamp 5 pack
3. Navigate to the unzipped folder and go to BootCamp/Drivers/Apple
4. Run AppleKeyboardInstaller64.exe
5. It will tell you that it's installed, but it won't work yet.
6. Open Device Manager and go to 'Human Interface Devices', right click Apple Keyboard and select "Update Driver Software"
7. Click 'Browse my computer for driver software', then 'Let me pick a list of device drivers on my computer'
8. Select the Apple Keyboard version 5 that you just installed (NOT the newest version 6).

Profit!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've managed to fix it with the following steps:

In the device manager, uninstall the following drivers and then restart your computer:

- Keyboards\Apple Keyboard (only the one with the warning sign, the
  other one is your macbook keyboard)
- Bluetooth\Device Identification Service
- Bluetooth\ xxx's Keyboard
- Bluetooth\Microsoft Bluetooth Enumerator
- Bluetooth\Microsoft Bluetooth LE Enumerator

Not sure if uninstalling all those devices is necessary, but this worked for me (only uninstalling the keyboard driver wasn't enough for me).

**Update:** This just reverts to the standard Windows Bluetooth drivers, unfortunately some things are not available (like fn+backspace for delete, fn+down/up for pgdown/pgup)

Answer (score -1):

I've used SharpKeys to map the eject key to del. works fine.. Often, after windows update runs apple's wireless keyboard and mouse no longer work.

One one occasion running Apple's software update showed and update to the bluetooth driver and installing and rebooting worked. That option does not always show up.

I mostly work on a mac these days.. With over 500 updates applied in 2 days, six reboots, I'd like to know if anyone has found an auto-fix-apple-keyboard-again script.